# In Paw, how can I use the response from a previous call, as a value in the body of another call?

Tags: json, http, paw-app

I use parsed values from previous responses for parts of the URL, or as the key in a JSON object.  However, I can't seem to be able to use them as the value of a field in a JSON object.

When I right click on the key, I have the option to do that,

[image]

but not when I right click on the value field.

[image]

I have tried following the instructions in the documentation, but the options listed in the documentation aren't available in the value portion of the JSON object in the body.  Would someone please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible because you're in a Number field. You can do this only on String fields for now. We're working on a fix for a future version, but it's not there yet.

The only alternative you can use is to format all your JSON, except this field, and convert to Text. The JSON structure will be preserved, and you can explicitly set the field inline with the text.

A quick screencast so show what I'm saying: http://cl.ly/141Y06380u2x

In this case you'll need to manually set a `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I find the answer fairly disappointing though. Any insight into why the choice was made to only allow this on string fields?

Comment: I agree with you, it clearly isn't a great behavior. The problem is because dynamic values should be inside what we call dynamic strings, and we have forced JSON numbers to be only numbers values, hence the problem. As we are working on a large refactoring of the data model, this will be fixed also…